# laravel load specific relation only for "auth" users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Is there any chance to make laravel only loading specific items when the user is authenticated?

Assuming this code:

```
public function getCategory(Category $category){

    $items = $category->products()->with(['otherRelation', 'favouriteUsers' => function($query){
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())->select(['product_id', 'user_id']);
        }])->withCount([
            'views',
    ])->latest()->paginate(20);
```

At the moment the `favouriteUsers` relation would be loaded, either the user is authenticated or not, is there any way I can prevent laravel from executing this query unless the user is authenticated?

Comment: try $items = $category->products()->with(['otherRelation'])->when(Auth::id(),function($query){
    $query->whereHas('favouriteUsers' , function($query){
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())->select(['product_id', 'user_id']);
    });
})
->withCount([
'views',
])->latest()->paginate(20);

Comment: Instead of `whereHas` it is `with` I think, isn't it?

Comment: if you need data then you can use with or else wherehas.wherehas wont return result of favouriteUsers .so if you are looking for data then use with

Comment: let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the relation `favoriteProducts()` in the `User::class`

That way it will be easier to get

```
$user = Auth::user();
$favoriteProducts = $user->favoriteProducts()
    ->with('otherRelation')
    ->withCount('views')
    ->whereHas('category', function($categoryQB) use($category) {
        $categoryQB->where('id', $category->id);
    })
    ->latest()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Not possible here, since the retrieved products should be all for the related category.
The `favouriteUsers` relation should only be loaded when authenticated, it's used in a template to perform a check if the user can favourite the product or not.